# How to increase size of all glyphs in FontForge?

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I opened a font file in FontForge. I want to enlarge all glyphs by 20%. I tried Element, Transformation, and Transform, but they did not work for me. How can I accomplish this? I am using FontForge 11.21.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why do you want to enlarge the glyphs in a font in fontforge?  Couldn't you just set a 20% larger font size and perhaps adjust the kerning when using the font in an application?

Comment: Also details matter. Scaling is sensitive to the point you scale about

Comment: I needed to do this before merging in glyphs from another font. There are reasons.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all glyphs (ctrl+a)
2. From menu choose Elements > Transformation > Transform.
3. Change the second dropdown to Scale Uniformly...
4. Change X and Y to 120%

Default checkboxes will automatically increase the kerning and width too.